# Difficulty with Visual Studio 2010 and WCF after Windows Automatic Update

Tags: asp.net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I will be as specific as I can, but honestly, I do not know where to look for the problem.

I was in the middle of actively writing some code on a visual studio project (VS 2010) on my laptop. That project communicates via WCF to the office server. During this activity, Windows automatic update decided to shutdown my machine, update, and reconfigure it, before automatically rebooting.

Now something has changed and I can no longer communicate durring debugging with the server application (maybe something with the ASP.Net development server?). I'm sure this is an easy fix--if you know where to look. (All my files seem intact and the project compiles normally without difficulty or error).

(As this service has been working correctly for many months, I really don't want to rebuild it.)

Can someone please tell me what Windows update changed? (I'm sorry if this is too vague, but I really don't know how to go about finding the setting(s) that were changed).

For what its worth, here is the app.config for the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <!--
  useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=true is needed to run handwriting recognition with IALoader.dll
 -->

<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>


<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true"/>
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_INovaDataService" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://xxxxxxxxxx:43175/NovaWebSite/Nova.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService"
    contract="DataService.INovaDataService" name="OfficeService" />
  <endpoint address="http://yyyyyyyyy:9000/Nova.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService"
    contract="DataService.INovaDataService" name="LibraryService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for any help with this (it is quit aggravating).

Comment: Can you browse to the server end point?

Comment: Restore your system before that update and it will be like before.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes. No problem bringing up the NovaDataService Service from the IE browser. What now?

Comment: @Harish Restore system? I'm not aware of any backups, besides, if I could restore it to before Windows Update, wouldn't that undo the update? So what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this can help anyone getting here. After many hours of study, I noticed that the project I needed as the start up project in the Visual Studio Solution was no longer checked. Somehow when Windows Update forced closed the Solution (VS 2010), it also changed the startup/main project to the ASP.Net Website (which is in my same solution as the client project). When the correct project was selected, all runs well once again. Don't know how this happened, but problem solved. Thanks everybody.